# Can a standard NEMA 5-15 outlet be installed in a round ceiling box?

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug

In my garage, I installed a series of 4" round ceiling boxes and put plastic (later ceramic) lamp bases on them for some basic lighting. This is the type of box I'm referring to:

[image]

<sup>Image courteously supplied by Lowes. No particular endorsement implied</sup>

I've recently purchased some plug-in LED light fixtures and would like to replace some of the lamp bases with a standard NEMA 5-15 outlet so I can plug in the lights.

- Will a standard 5-15 outlet *fit* properly in this box?
- Is there an appropriate cover plate that can be used?
- As an alternative, is it safe/legal to clip the plug and hard-wire these otherwise plug-in lights directly to the Romex in the boxes?

If the answer to either is "no", then I guess I'll have to pull the boxen and replace them with standard rectangular boxes, but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They do make receptacles designed to fit round boxes, for example a Leviton 1228 (I'm sure other brands have it as well, this was just the first I found when I googled `Round Box Receptacle`):

[image]

Depending in the screw holes on your box, you may also be able to fit a standard duplex receptacle and fit a wall plate designed for that purpose. These act as a wall plate and mounting bracket/adapter for mounting a standard receptacle in the round box.

[image]

Finally, if all you need is an ungrounded two prong plug, the easiest option might be to get some light bulb to socket adapter, like these GE 54276:

[image]

Comment: Porcelain fixture w/ outlet.

Comment: This does, indeed, answer the question I asked. Unfortunately, I asked the wrong question. :( I'd actually installed 4" _square metal_ boxes, not round plastic*. The good news is that there are _plenty_ of duplex outlet cover plates available for that setup, and I was able to find them at `<local big-box retailer>`. I picked up a couple of samples, realized that I grabbed 2 _different_ styles out of the same pile, realized I like one better than the other and will get more of those. *In my defense, I'd just installed a round plastic on the back porch - it was on my mind.

Answer (score 3):

PhilippNagel nailed it.  The only thing I would add is don't put GFCI devices on the ceiling (must be reachable) and don't use cord and plug connections above a drop ceiling.

Comment: Is it legal to snip the plug and hard wire it?

Comment: If your plugs are open-air, i.e. You can visually see them and (to the point) observe if they are smoking or smell the smoke, then cord and plug is absolutely fine.   If the plugs are behind a drop ceiling, then you may snip the plugs and hardwire into proper strain reliefs *if* the appliance cord has the correct  labeling for use as cordage.  Which most do.

Comment: The boxes are attached to the roof trusses and there is no ceiling - just bare trusses, so I may just do that and skip the outlets. Put on some sort of blanking cover with an appropriate punch-out and a cable clamp and call it a day.

Comment: All receptacles in a garage shall be GFCI protected as per NATIONAL ELECTRICAL CODE!