# Best way to install duplex receptacle in ceiling. 3" round box

Tags: receptacle, ceiling

So I had initially planned for hard wired light fixtures in my shop. I've had a recent change of plans due to finding an option that I like more.

The problem is I installed 3" round boxes, and now need plugs. I have 5/8 drywall for the ceiling. What's the best way to get a duplex in the ceiling, be it adapt to this box that has 2 3/4 screw spacing or rip out the box and install new.

[image: Box in question]

Comment: Look at this answer, https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/176408/can-a-standard-nema-5-15-outlet-be-installed-in-a-round-ceiling-box

Comment: Though it looks like getting a box that can accommodate some outlets is likely the least of your worries.  It doesn't look like you have nearly enough cable accessible to make any connections.  I believe code typically dictates a minimum of 6" inside your box (and in my experience, that's truly the minimum to be able to easily make connections). 
 Hopefully you have extra slack outside the boxes, or else you're going to need to pull new cable to give you the working length you need.

Comment: Good looking out, but the cable was pushed back up in the box for drywall which is still being finished. Made sure not to short myself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid doing more drywall I would swap that out for a 2 gang old work box and install two outlets. The box and outlet cover should cover the opening since the dimensions are 3.75" x 4". Then you have future expansion since you can never have enough light in a shop

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution I've settled on, should be a quick enough fix as well.